# Bootstrap: First div runs off a little when i use <div class="row-fluid">

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8079/w5hk.png

I can't figure out why this occurs only in 'row-fluid'.
The first div will run off a lil. It works perfectly fine in < div class="row" > but not with < div class="row-fluid" >

Code:

```
  <div id="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6 offset3" >Hello 1</div>
          <div class="span6 offset3" >Hello 2</div>
          <div class="span6 offset3" >Hello 3</div>
          <div class="span6 offset3" >Hello 4</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your photo doesn't work.  A js fiddle would be better yet.

Answer (score 0):

By default, fluid containers are still based on a 12 column layout; their widths are just percentages instead of fixed values.

You have 36 columns in your markup right now (`.span6` * 4 = 24 columns plus `.offset3` * 4 = 12 columns, for a total of 36 columns). 36 columns will not fit into a 12 column layout.

You should try changing your classes to "span3" or "span2 offset1", but in some way, the total must always equal 12.

Additionally, you need to make your container class "container-fluid" as well.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't catch you. Its my first attempt with Bootstrap's offset. No explanation given in the site.

Was trying to centralise a .span6 div. 12 column layout< Correct. Since '.span6 * 4 = 24' which exceeds 12 cols. That would mean I could not use it when it involves offset?

Comment: To center a span6 in a 12 column layout you would simply use: `<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6 offset3">Content in here</div></div>`. Each content item would be in its own `<div class="row-fluid">` and all fluid rows should be within a single `<div class="container-fluid">`